# Popup: Opening popup using TextBox IsKeyboardFocused = true datatrigger, and closing popup using StaysOpen="False", causing popup to not display

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, popup, datatrigger

I'm trying to have a popup open up when the textbox gains keyboard focus. When the user clicks off the popup, I want the popup to close.

From what I can gather `StaysOpen="False"` makes the popup close when the user clicks off of it. The problem is that it doesn't work together with the `IsKeyboardFocused = true` datatrigger and causes the popup to not show up at all. If I remove the `StaysOpen` property, the popup shows up, **but closes when it is clicked** (Even though I have no code specifying a closed event).

[Here is what it looks like without the `StaysOpen` property.](https://i.imgur.com/gWbeJUB.gifv)

Here is my code. Any help is much appreciated thanks!

```
    <TextBox x:Name="SearchTextBox" 
             Height="26" 
             Width="165"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="Example">
    </TextBox>
    <Popup
           Placement="Bottom"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=SearchTextBox}"
           Height="200"
           Width="100"
           StaysOpen="False"> <!-- If StaysOpen property is removed, popup displays!!! -->
        <Popup.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Popup}">
                <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=SearchTextBox, Path=IsKeyboardFocused}"
                                 Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Popup.Style>
    </Popup>
```